# How to create RollingFileAppender at runtime (web application Listener) and replace ConsoleApender defined in configuration xml

Tags: java, log4j2

I'm using log4j2 beta 4. log4j2.xml is properly set, everything works fine. But i need to change appender in runtime. From console defined in xml to RollingFileAppender with specific file location.

I'm struggling with documentation and getting nowhere. Anybody solved this?

Answer (score 0):

You could write a code which would be invoked at startup of your app and there you colud remove the appender from the list of root loggers.

It goes something like this. I'm not very sure.

```
Logger.getRootLogger().removeAppender("stdout")
```

can I take a look at log4j.properties file?

Comment: logback. Done some comparison. I couldnt tell you why I decided to stick with log4j2.

Comment: My bad. I dint not notice the '2' after log4j. Anyway, I haven't used log4j2 but i'm pretty sure that there wont be modifications in the configuration. You might also want to take a look at Logback. Its awesome!

Comment: The API was reduced. It is no longer possible to add/remove Appends in the Logger-Interface, it must be done in the configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

to whom it may concern.

Created custom appender as plugin (basically copy of RollinfFileAppender) which gave me the oportunity to change file location. And created RootLogger (again as plugin) which gave me the oportunity to change log level and switch between sysout and file depending on server.

Sounds easy now:-)

Comment: If you're using Maven, a better approach is to create `src/main/resources/log4j2.xml` and `src/test/resources/log4j2-test.xml`. The `log4j2.xml` contains the `RollingFileAppender` and the `log4j2-test.xml` contains the `ConsoleAppender`. Read the following link for more information: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#UnitTestingInMaven

Answer (score 0):

define a logger with the filename/filepath defined by a system property in your log4j2.xml file.

```
<appenders>
<File name="MyFile" fileName="${sys:logFilename}.log">
  <PatternLayout pattern="%d{${datestamp}} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
</File>
</appenders>
```

In your programm read the filename from user input, save it to a system property with the key you used in your configuration file for the filename. update the context to reload your configuration file. --> Filename is created dynamicaly at runtime.

```
String filnameInput = "GetInputLikeYouWantIt";
System.setProperty("logFilename", filnameInput);
//update the Logger context to relead the filename with the lookup
LoggerContext ctx =  (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
ctx.reconfigure();
```